# How come the second wand configuration shoots faster than the first?

Tags: noita

I have a no-shuffle wand with 2 spells per cast and the following spells in it:

Chainsaw | add mana | projectile area teleport | double scatter | energy sphere

I find that if I swap the 1st and 2nd spell, the wand fires much faster, but I don't understand why. So that would be

add mana | Chainsaw | projectile area teleport | double scatter | energy sphere

I thought I understood spell wrapping, namely that if the wand tries to cast a spell block of more than 1 spell but it reaches the end of the wand's slots without finding enough spells to cast, it would start at the first slot again and grab the first spell it finds to copy into the last spell-block.
However this would not explain the faster casting speed of the second configuration, so I must be missing something?

### Slow firing spell order

[image: Slow firing spell config]

### Fast firing spell order

[image: Fast firing spell config]

If it helps, you can also see both in action here: [Different rates of fire caused by chainsaw location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iAeT.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I'll note that no wrapping is occurring here, and also that the limiting factor here in the slow configuration is your cast delay rather than your recharge time. Basic reason: in slow config, Add Mana & Energy Sphere have their cast delays added together, in fast config they don't.

### Details

You're using a 2 spells/cast wand. What's being cast in the slow configuration every time is:

```
1.a Chainsaw
1.b Add Mana | Proj. Area Teleport | Double Scatter | Energy Sphere
```

`1.a` and `1.b` happen at the same time, but `1.b` is clearly the slower one: Add Mana has +0.17s cast delay, this is being applied to the Energy Sphere which also has +0.17s cast delay, for a total of +0.34s cast delay on top of your wand's innate cast delay. This total has ended up being even longer than the wand's recharge, so each time you cast the wand, the recharge timer actually completes before the cast delay cooldown of `1.b` completes so you still have to wait for that.

Now let's look at the fast configuration:

```
1.a Add Mana | Chainsaw
1.b Proj. Area Teleport | Double Scatter | Energy Sphere
```

Now `1.b` only has +0.17s cast delay from the Energy Sphere, while `1.a`'s cast delay happens at the same time (although the Chainsaw sets everything before it to zero anyway).

### Tip for spotting this

If you look at the recharge bar on the top right in each clip, you can see that it's only on the screen for about half the time in the slow configuration. This is a clue that cast delay is your limiting factor.

### Sidenote: Clarification on wrapping

In this wand it seems like you were hoping to wrap in order to cast the Add Mana & the Chainsaw twice. As you mentioned wrapping in your question I'll go into some detail. There are two things here to consider when trying to make wrapping happen:

1. The spell can't wrap to re-cast stuff it just cast in the same overall block, so `1.b`'s Double Scatter is unable to wrap around to cast the Add Mana/Chainsaw again (visual example: they're already on the Holy Mountain backwall, they can't show up twice at the same time on that wall)
2. Not directly an issue here, but worth remembering that wands with >1 spells/cast like your 2 spells/cast wand won't attempt to wrap just from there being a "spell/cast" remaining - they need a motivation to seek to wrap, such as a Double Scatter (seeks to cast the 2 spells to its right), or a modifier like Add Mana (seeks to cast the 1 spell to its right; you can think of basic modifiers as being exactly like a dualcast/tricast/etc but are just a single cast instead).
   To fix issue 1 above, you might try the following layout with those spells:

```
[Add Mana | Chainsaw | Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere | Double Scatter]
1.a Add Mana | Chainsaw
1.b Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere
2.a Double Scatter | [2.a.i: Add Mana | Chainsaw] | [2.a.ii] | [Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere]
2.b There's nothing remaining to seek to put into the second Spell/Cast of block 2, so the cast ends here
```

This doesn't give you any extra energy efficiency - Add Mana, Chainsaw, Proj. Area Teleport, and Energy Sphere all get cast the same amount of times as one another - but since you're casting Chainsaw twice per pass through the wand, you'll get -0.34s of recharge time from it, so you'll likely be limited only by the `Wand Cast Delay + 0.17s Energy Sphere` cast delay of block `2.b`. Or, better yet, use the Light in your inventory:

```
[Add Mana | Chainsaw | Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere | Light]
1.a Add Mana | Chainsaw
1.b Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere
2.a Light | Add Mana | Chainsaw
2.b Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere
```

Now the wand doesn't have the Double Scatter ruining the accuracy of everything in the block, but still makes use of the Light to force a wrap and recast everything. Or, better even still:

```
[Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere | Add Mana | Chainsaw | Light]
1.a Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere
1.b Add Mana | Chainsaw
2.a Light | Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere
2.b Add Mana | Chainsaw
```

Now the Chainsaw is properly setting the cast delay to zero of everything before it (i.e. everything, now). Recharge time is guaranteed to be your only limiter now, and if the wand recharge is less than 0.35s that means you're firing at the 60 frames per second tick rate now. Of course, Projectile Area Teleport is quite mana hungry so at this point you will almost certainly be rate limited by mana recharge (wand costs 103 mana per full usage which takes two frames for you to do since two casts are occurring; required mana recharge would be `60fps * 103mana / 2frames = 3090mps`). It's very likely an even better layout would be:

```
[Add Mana | Chainsaw | Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere | Luminous Drill | Light]
1.a Add Mana | Chainsaw
1.b Proj. Area Teleport | Energy Sphere
2.a Luminous Drill
2.b Light | Add Mana | Chainsaw
```

The purpose of this layout is to try to cast our Add Mana more frequently than we cast the expensive parts of the wand. Now we pay 33 manacost per cast of the wand instead of 103 (although we do only cast the Energy Sphere once). As a side bonus the Luminous Drill reduces recharge even more, but it would be nice to have something cheaper like a second chainsaw or drill there instead. Now the mana per second drained by the wand is only `60fps * 33mana / 2frames = 990`, we sacrificed fire rate by half but reduced mana drain by two thirds.

In practice both will probably still be emptying your wand instantly, so let's compare behaviour of the last two wands pretending you have a pretty standard wand with 500 mana and 150 mana recharge:

1. Fast inefficient wand - takes about 10 frames (~0.17s) to cast 10 energy spheres in a blast, then hopefully fires ~3 energy spheres per second as it recharges 150/s and spends ~50/sphere. Behaviour gets a bit janky with drained wands though so you'll probably be firing off some random non-homing spheres but firing a bit more than 3 per second.
2. Slower efficient wand - takes about 30 frames (~0.5s) to cast 15 energy spheres in a blast, then hopefully fires ~4.5 energy spheres per second as it recharges 150/s and spends ~33/sphere. Again expect some jank that's hard to quantify.

You'll find this is a common pattern with medium-to-high level simple machine gun wands - firing at 60fps drains almost any wand to zero since even an unmodified 20 mana Energy Sphere would require 1200 mana recharge to sustain, never mind modifiers, so you're better off trying to (1) only cast your expensive high power stuff in one of two ticks that your wand executes to halve the drain, and (2) try to arrange your Add Mana to get cast in *both* frames so you can hit zero or very near zero total manacost.